# How to install Db2 Express C on my MacOSX Yosemite?

Tags: macos, db2

> How to install Db2 Express C on my MacOSX Yosemite?

MyApproach:

I searched various threads on StackOverflow but I am 
not able to download the software from the link:

> http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/db2/express-c/download.html

It is because I am not able to see where the link is for Downloading DB2 for MacOS X Yosemite.
There are only these versions available (32 and 64 bit) of windows and  Linux
1)And not particular link for MACOS X

> Can anyone guide me Why I am also new to Mac?

@Edit
2)Am I doing Intallation Wrong.What are the causes.Please Explain me how to install all of them?

[image: In Expc Folder[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9X17.png)

[image]

Db2 Setup LaunchPad is showing blank. 
I am also following this thread:

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014927797

But I don't know how to how to do the first step also.

How to create  /etc/sysctl.conf. Create the file /etc/sysctl.conf if it does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

DB2 Express-C for Mac OS X appears to be in a state of flux. It's not listed on the download page that you link to, but if you look at the main DB2 Express-C page (http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/db2/express-c/index.html), you'll see the link near the bottom

> [DB2 Express-C for Mac OS X Officially Released (Feb 23, 2012)](http://www.ibm.com/services/forms/preLogin.do?source=swg-db2expressc&S_PKG=dlmacosx)

Comment: I have installed  the Software from the above link.I unzipped it and I get a expc folder.In that folder I clicked on db2setup.And the following errors I pointed in the Edit of my Ans